# How to configure a cluster or know your configuration is OK?

Tags: python, bigdata, dask, data-processing

I have huge files to process. I have the need to perform a set_index on one column of each file.

I've read that set_index is really expensive and that we should lower our number of partitions. I've tried but that does not help for now.

What is needed to be able to perform this kind of operation on huge datasets ? 
What the ideal size for a partition according to the memory associated with both worker and threads ?

I've noticed that if I set 8 workers for example and if I have either 30GB, 70GB or 100GB per worker, I think something is wrong in my configuration (on a single node for now but hopefully in cluster mode soon) :

- The memory used is not even / balanced between the workers, one might die.
- I have the line of log with `Event loop was unresponsive in Worker for 12.02s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability` Is it an issue or not at all ?
- My worker are dying one by one until I've lost all my workers
- I can keep only one worker / many threads sharing the whole memory but the process will be really slow and I think it will finish (one day ...)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading through [Dask's best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html).

Your question is very broad, and so unfortunately the answer is too.  In general the answer to your question will depend strongly on how you are using Dask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link. Can you give me an idea of how many disk or memory is needed depending on the data we want to process ? 
If we have only 10GB per worker to process 10TB of data, do you think it can be an issue ?  
I think it also depends a lot about the configuration of the dask cluster as well ...
Thanks in advance !

Comment: It depends entirely on the computation that you want to do.  It is possible to run some computations on very small amounts of memory.  Other computations require far more memory than the data that you have.  It all depends.

Comment: Thanks. And if the computation is a set_index on a large file ?

Comment: I've updated my question. Could you give me some clues ? Thanks a lot ! ;)